# ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: rooms.number

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

Could someone please help me figure this one out? It's my first week working with Rails and all my tests pass but the one below. I understand it's due to the unique constraint but I don't know what else exactly I need to do.

```
    Error:
RoomsControllerTest#test_should_create_room:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: rooms.number: INSERT INTO "rooms" ("number", "capacity", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
    app/controllers/rooms_controller.rb:31:in `block in create'
    app/controllers/rooms_controller.rb:30:in `create'
    test/controllers/rooms_controller_test.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <class:RoomsControllerTest>'
    test/controllers/rooms_controller_test.rb:19:in `block in <class:RoomsControllerTest>'
```

This is the create method in the rooms_controller:

```
def create
    @room = Room.new(room_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @room.save
        format.html { redirect_to rooms_path, notice: 'Room was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @room }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @room.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

This is the test itself:

```
  test "should create room" do
    assert_difference('Room.count') do
      post rooms_url, params: { room: { capacity: @room.capacity, number: @room.number } }
    end

    assert_redirected_to rooms_url
  end
```

Schema - `unique:true` so the same number won't get added twice:

```
  create_table "rooms", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "number"
    t.integer "capacity"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["number"], name: "index_rooms_on_number", unique: true
  end
```

I reset my test db with the following commands:

```
bundle exec rake db:drop RAILS_ENV=test
bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So for some reason you already have a room with that number. My best guess is that the `@room` ivar used in your test is already persisted to the database. To make the test pass, you should probably avoid relying on `@room` or discard it entirely if you can, and pass a number of your choice instead.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Matthieu! Yes, I had initially hardcoded @room.capacity and @room.number and it worked. But whenever I reverted it back to using @room (after  running `bundle exec rake db:reset RAILS_ENV=test`)... the test would fail again! Haha I was wondering if maybe it was just my bias - finding a way to get the test to pass and maybe bypassing the real problem. :) I guess I'll have to research a bit more about the Rails test env.